# Break out of unknown number of nested loops without using go to?

Tags: php, loops, nested-loops, break, goto

I am writing some code which will frequently contain loops that I need to break out of under certain conditions. The problem is that sometimes, I am nested 3 levels deep, some times 4 and some times 5 or more.

I could break out by writing `break 3`, `break 4` and `break 5` etc. but that requires me to keep track of the current depth inside each nested loop. Is there an easier way of breaking out of unknown number of nested loops without using `goto`?

---

I think the question needs a little more explanation.

1. There are 4 nested `for` loops in part of a code.
2. Somewhere down the line there are 3 nested `for` loops.
3. Then somewhere else there are 5 nested `for` loops.

There are all independent of each other and I only have to go through one of them for each run of the code. The one I loop through depends on value of certain parameters.

I could break out of them by keeping track of `for` loops in each case and using `break number` but doing it for 100-200 different sets of nested `for` loops is tiring. It will also not work if the number of nested loops have to be updated.

I was hoping that there is some code in PHP which could just break out of all loops at once without me keeping track.

Comment: Possibly breaking up the code into a separate function which can return when needed?

Comment: why not put them in a function and break out by using `return`?

Comment: I can't think of *any* reason the answer wouldn't be "refactor your code so that you never need anything besides `break`, `continue` ... or `return`.

Comment: return will get you out of a function, or you can throw a special type of exception and catch only exceptions of that type. Programming is usually considered binary, but there's always the 3rd state: exceptions, unknown, undefined, no answer, etc.

Comment: How can the number of nested loops be unknown? Does the loop you need to break out of determined dynamically?

Comment: @Barmar It know the value but it is different for 80 different sections of code and using `break number` requires me to count the loops every time. I was looking of a more unified way of doing things so that I need to write the breaking out line only once. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the depth of the loop you want to break out of, but not how many levels down you are from that, you can use a variable that each loop checks.

```
$break_level = 99;
while (...) {
    while (...) {
        while (...) {
            while (...) {
                ...
                if (...) {
                    $break_level = 2;
                    break;
                }
                ...
            }
            if ($break_level <= 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($break_level <= 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($break_level <= 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But this kind of generality is hardly ever needed. I've written millions of loops in my lifetime, and I hardly ever need to break out of anything other than the current loop, its immediate container, or the entire set of nested loops. In these cases there's often a variable that can be checked. For instance, if you're searching a multidimensional array, just set a `$found` variable:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($array as $level1) {
    foreach ($level1 as $level2) {
        if (...) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A coder dies every time someone uses this in production.

Comment: "That is there some fancy code! 'being never used more than 3 levels myself.." D:

Comment: Thanks @Barmer. I was hoping there would be some function or code snippet that would break out of all loops without me keeping track of it and using something simple like the `break` statements themselves.

Comment: @RealNoob I'm being serious. I like "never" use more 3 or more levels myself. Even 2 is relatively uncommon - this is probably saying something about *too much nesting*.

Comment: @user2864740 I have to deal with 5 or 6 variables looping through all their values. This is the first time I am dealing with so many loops as well. Most of the times, 2 were sufficient.

Comment: @RealNoob *If* one could take a step back and re-write the current method's code [ie. given no constraints on 'looking like' the original], would this code benefit? Is there a way to 'pull up' the loops, even recursively, over data-structures? Are any of the loops independent wrt. early termination? I don't want to get too X-Y, but it's probably a sorta ugly X :D

Comment: @user2864740 I have updated the question to add more details. Are `goto` statements actually that bad? I think they are the only ones which could solve this problem for me.

Comment: @RealNoob I've seen very few counter-examples of `goto` solving a problem better (and it often comes down to language; as many languages offer better methods of problem decomposition), but they *do* exist.. all I can say, is I don't call them "evil" even if they might as well usually be "forgotten" :}

Comment: @RealNoob The problem is "doing it for 100-200 different sets of nested for loops" (and other indicators of a systematic code issues) .. *the code is killing you*. Sorry that you have to deal with it, but take control or else it'll eat your soul (that makes it .. "evil"?) >_<

Comment: @RealNoob I've updated the answer to add a less general, but more realistic solution.

Comment: @user2864740 For now, I have decided to use `goto` but will keep looking for a better solution. Thanks for the help and advice. :)